# Angle bisectors in a right triangle

Tags: geometry

In triangle $\Delta ABC$ $\measuredangle C = 90^{\circ}$. The angle bisectors of angles $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ cross at point $O$. The distance from point $d\left(O,\overline{AC}\right)=3\operatorname{cm}$ and $d\left(O,\overline{AB}\right)=15\operatorname{cm}$  Find the perimeter of triangle $\Delta ABC$ in cm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$O$ is the center of inscribed circle.

Let $M$, $N$ and $P$  be the tangent points of $AC$, $AB$ and  $BC$ respectively, and $AN=AM=x, NB=BP=y, x+y=15, CP=CN=3$ 
Then, perimeter $P=(x+y)+(y+3)+(3+x)=36$